# How to make plain(cut) shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, transforms

I'm sure the question was asked a lot, but i cannot formulate it for google.
I have this quadrangle[image]
When look at it from side, it's not plane[image]
While zero smooth it's two triangles with different shades, I would make it into one quadrangle with single shade. Any easy way?

Comment: omg why my brain works so slow
i found solution in **using G+G** instead of _manually rotating edges and moving single vertices_

Comment: The reality is that quads have a limit in how much you can bend them before you run into non planar faces. To describe curved surfaces **you need more geometry**, more quads that stay flat (keep your geometry planar) but as a sum describe the shape you are after.

Comment: found another one solution. If you already have 3 vertices and need one more for quadrangle, then add edge between vertices that should be connected to new vertex you need. Then subdivide the edge, scale this new vertex from opposite vertex in the quadrangle. Then cut in proper camera view with background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *non-planar* geometry.
Shading issues are typical for such faces.

To make it planar, just scale it along it's *Normal* to zero.

[image]

Comment: Ooh, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :). You can now mark the answer as accepted ✔.

Comment: i guess it is impossible to make face planar while affecting only one vertex?

Comment: Do you mean to move only one vertex? Or to keep a specific vertex at it's position?

Comment: keep all but one

Comment: It can be done quite easily using the 3D cursor, but please ask this as a new question :).